# Steps on how to install PyQT for Windows 7?

Tags: installation, pyqt

I haven't come across any step-by-step guide (ones I've found are outdated, and one on riverbankcomputing is too confusing), and was wondering if I could get any help. I've been on a wild goose chase thus far

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to the [download page](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download) and install the executable there. That should help you get started.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the binary installer is no longer available (at time of writing). It looks like you've got install the QT SDK and then build PyQT

Comment: the binary installers are available now, just keep scrolling down on http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download

Comment: Thanks matt - I've used the updated ones.

Comment: You're welcome. I would delete your answer now, as it no longer applies.

Answer (score 1):

actually the page that download link goes to is pretty confusing.  the latest version of pyqt4 is 4.10.  about midway down the page there are what appear to be 'legacy' versions (i.e. 4.8 ).  I noticed that when I click that link for the executable - it actually serves up 4.10 which is the latest fuly automagical installation.

Comment: same holds for qt5 but know that if you want to run them side by side it looks like you have to go through the hassle of building from source